# JS, save svg to png error with xlink:href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, d3.js

I try to save svg to png in client side.
Follow this instruction http://techslides.com/save-svg-as-an-image/
It can save fine if not have img in svg or img not have attributes xlink:href.
Error:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 215: Namespace prefix xlink for href on image is not defined
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Anyone have experience, plz help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the xlink namespace since that's what the error suggests. In d3 that would be:

```
.attr("xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")
```

Comment: I add it to <image> in svg. It not through error but, file png I don't see image. Sorry for the defay Because I am checking my code :)

Comment: images is going to tiny after canvas draw. How can fix it?

Comment: Ask another question if you want another answer.